# Tailwind CSS does not load Background Images in React App

Tags: reactjs, background-image, tailwind-css

I am using React with Tailwind CSS and trying to set a background image for one div. However, the background image isn't showing despite setting the tailwind.config.js and saving the image in the right place.

Is there something I am missing which gets Tailwind to load background images properly?

Here is my tailwind.config.js including the image I want to load called "background.jpg"

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      'background': "url('src/images/background.jpg')"
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

The Component (I have listed bg-background in the className):

```
        <div className="App">
          <div className="container px-2 py-2 min-w-full bg-background">
            <div className="flex h-screen bg-red">
            <div className="m-auto">
           <h1 className="text-5xl">Element Reference App</h1>
           </div>
           </div>
</div>
    </div>
```

The file structure:

[image]

Comment: `backgroundImage` property is added as an Object in the docs https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image Could it be the reason?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to put the background image file in the `public` directory of your project. Then you can use `url('/background.jpg')` in Tailwind.

That will also work when you build for production. I doubt if using the `src` directory will work after building, because it will probably not be in the production dist.

Answer (score 0):

The extend section in the tailwind.config.js is wrong. the Pictures must be exported as objects.

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      'background': "url('src/images/background.jpg')"
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Must be changed to

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
     backgroundImage: { 'background': "url('/src/images/background.jpg')" }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: but what when background-image comes from API?
How can I set API response in tailwind config file?

Comment: @MrPatel2021 Replied to your question above.

Answer (score 0):

To answer @MrPatel2021, question above:

> but what when background-image comes from API? How can I set API
> response in tailwind config file?

To achieve this, you need to do it inline:

```
<div className="bg-[url('path-to-your-remote-image.png')]">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Use `tailwind-merge` (recommended) or `clsx` lib to merge or join other class names.